# Hide a button depending on ACL

Tags: acl

I want to know if there is code to hide a button when logged in.

I can hide a module/menu item by using the built in ACL features, but how can I do it from a code perspective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way is to check if the user has an id - if so it means the user is logged in. If id = 0 then it's a guest user and you can show the button as below:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();

if($user->id == 0)
{
    // Code to run for non-logged in users.
}
```

---

#### Update:

You can find some examples on how to accomplish various conditional tasks using the user info in these JSE Q/A:

- [How to display user profile information?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/899/how-to-display-user-profile-information/902#902)
- [How to know which usergroup/specific access level user belongs to](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/18357/how-to-know-which-usergroup-specific-access-level-user-belongs-to)
- [How to detect if user is Super User?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/1150/how-to-detect-if-user-is-super-user)
- [Joomla 3.x: Check if user belongs to 2 groups](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17725/joomla-3-x-check-if-user-belongs-to-2-groups)

Comment: if you just want to use some short code in the text editor (so as not to use code as in the above answer), there are plugins that'll let you do this sort of thing. One such plugin is Content Filter by Function90 (there's a free version too). I find it useful to just hide elements right in the article editor.

Comment: @BrianPeat I suppose I could use Regular Labs Snippets too, can they do this?

Comment: @FFrewin what if I wanted to choose a specific user group?  I'm assuming I can do something similar to the above but instead of using id use the user group?

Comment: Where would I find information like this?  I tried J Docs but it's useless.  I found lots of deleted pages.

Comment: @Eoin no, but he's got a perfectly good extension called Conditional Content that'll do it.

Comment: @Eoin: I updated my answer

Comment: @FFrewin thanks!  Some fantastic resources there absolutely brilliant.